# Oracle refresh materialized view ON STATEMENT

Tags: database, oracle, materialized-views

Does Oracle support ON STATEMENT refreshing of materialized views?

It seems to be documented here under the section "About ON STATEMENT Refresh for Materialized Views": https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/refresh.htm#DWHSG8363

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW sales_mv_onstat
REFRESH FAST ON STATEMENT USING TRUSTED CONSTRAINT
AS
SELECT s.rowid sales_rid, c.cust_first_name first_name, c.cust_last_name 
last_name,
   p.prod_name prod_name, 
s.quantity_sold quantity_sold, s.amount_sold amount_sold
FROM sh.sales s, sh.customers c, sh.products p
WHERE s.cust_id = c.cust_id and s.prod_id = p.prod_id;
```

But when I try to use it, I get "ORA-00905: missing keyword". It seems only ON DEMAND and ON COMMIT are supported.

Comment: ON STATEMENT Refresh was added in Oracle 12.2. Are you sure you aren't using an older version?

Comment: You are correct. I was using Oracle in AWS RDS and noticed only version 12.1 is supported.